# Create a dictionary with 4 keys assigning values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a list that is 400+ items, but I need to ultimately parse it into a dataframe in pandas with 4 columns.  So I thought it would be good to convert the list so that each of the 4 items received the appropriate value from the list.

```
list = ['1','ABC','ABC001,'ABC002,'2','ABC','ABC001','ABC003','3','DEF','DEF001','DEF001']
```

I want to make a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
Dict = {'Id' : '1', 'TopSite' : 'ABC', 'Floor' : 'ABC001', 'Room' : 'ABC002', 'Id' : '2'.... }
```

So I tried the following:

```
columns = ['Id', 'TopSite', 'Floor', 'Room']
list = ['1','ABC','ABC001,'ABC002,'2','ABC','ABC001','ABC003','3','DEF','DEF001','DEF001']
DataDict = [dict(zip(columns, regionDataList))]
```

The problem is that it only gives me the very first 4 items in the list in the dictionary.

Comment: Your example output has a single `dict` with repeated keys. That's not possible. Do you want one `dict` for each four values? Or do you not understand how `dict`s work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a step to iterate through your list so you can repeat the `dict(zip(...))` for each chunk of items corresponding to the number of columns (assuming that what you really want is a list of dicts - a bit different than your example output). Something like:

```
cols = ['Id', 'TopSite', 'Floor', 'Room']
items = ['1','ABC','ABC001','ABC002','2','ABC','ABC001','ABC003','3','DEF','DEF001','DEF001']

results = [dict(zip(cols, items[i:i + len(cols)])) for i in range(0, len(items), len(cols))]

print(results)
# OUTPUT
# [{'Id': '1', 'TopSite': 'ABC', 'Floor': 'ABC001', 'Room': 'ABC002'}, {'Id': '2', 'TopSite': 'ABC', 'Floor': 'ABC001', 'Room': 'ABC003'}, {'Id': '3', 'TopSite': 'DEF', 'Floor': 'DEF001', 'Room': 'DEF001'}]
```

Of course, you really don't need the interim step if your goal is to convert to dataframe. You can get there by passing your columns list as parameter along with a chunked up version of your items list. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Id', 'TopSite', 'Floor', 'Room']
items = ['1','ABC','ABC001','ABC002','2','ABC','ABC001','ABC003','3','DEF','DEF001','DEF001']
chunks = [items[i:i + len(cols)] for i in range(0, len(items), len(cols))]

df = pd.DataFrame(chunks, columns=cols)
print(df)
# OUTPUT
#   Id TopSite   Floor    Room
# 0  1     ABC  ABC001  ABC002
# 1  2     ABC  ABC001  ABC003
# 2  3     DEF  DEF001  DEF001
```

As an aside, both examples will run faster for large lists if you handle the `len(...)` bits with variables rather than running them over and over inside the comprehensions.